# Text Countdown Timer Inside Push Notification

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, apple-push-notifications

I would like to have a timer inside my iOS push notification. Like when it comes down from the top of the screen, I want it to say `You have \(time - 1) seconds to respond!` How can I code that?

Comment: You can’t. The notification comes from the APNS ( Apple push notification server)

Comment: Instead of showing Apple's push notification banner, Create your own to display when the app is open.

Answer (score 0):

Not saying I would do this, but you could check out the "apns-collapse-id" key in the APNs header. It allows you to send multiple push notifications, and each one will replace the last. You could send one push "You have 120 seconds to respond!" and then 30 seconds later, using the same collapse id, send another "You have 90 seconds to respond". The previous push will be replaced with this one.